# How to add Facebook share/like icon in Blog Entry header?

Tags: nodes, social-network

I want to add a header to my "blog entry" content type that will have a couple icons for sharing with Facebook, Twitter, email, and Google +1.

How can I do this?

I currently have the icons in a block in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

The AddToAny module lets you do this.  You choose to have the button show in the content, and then use a negative weight to float the button to the top of your content (aka the header section).

Answer (score 0):

Below are some alternatives to pick from (quotes are from their project pages).

## Modules with a stable D7 release:

- [ShareThis](http://drupal.org/project/sharethis):

  > Integration with the ShareThis social bookmarking utility on selected node types.
  >
  > The code for this project was based on the original share project for Drupal 5.x. The code for this project has been trimmed down to only work with the ShareThis system, and not require any additional modules to work properly.
- [Service Links](http://drupal.org/project/service_links):

  > Service Links facilitates the adding of social networks links or javascript buttons within the content with a special focus on developers and themers interested to extend their number or customize their displaying. Built on Drupal for Drupal doesn't include commercial advertising or spying hidden code and doesn't require third part libraries.
  >
  > The services included are various: del.icio.us, Digg, Facebook/Facebook Share/Facebook Like, Furl, Google Bookmark/Google Plus One, IceRocket, LinkedIn/Linkedin button counter, MySpace, Newsvine, Reddit, StumbleUpon, Technorati, Twitter/Twitter widget, Yahoo Bookmark, and many more, they are split for language in different packages: basque, dutch, farsi, german, hungarian, italian, polish, russian, spanish, swedish.
  >
  > Other services are availables to be included within an extra module which can be built easily through a web interface.
- [ShareBar](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharebar):

  > The Drupal Sharebar module lets you easily add a "floating" social media submission bar on your website (like that found on Mashable) that includes share buttons for the most popular social media websites online such as Facebook, Twitter, and Google +1 Buttons.
- [Share Buttons by AddToAny](https://www.drupal.org/project/addtoany):

  > Share buttons for Drupal including AddToAny's universal sharing button, Facebook, Twitter, Google+, Pinterest, WhatsApp and many more.
  >
  > Large vector share buttons use AddToAny SVG sharing icons. AddToAny vector icons load efficiently, are mathematically precise, scalable to any size, and stunning on High-PPI screens such as Retina and Retina HD displays.
- [Easy Social](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_social):

  > Centered in a single place, you don't need to worry in including external javascript libraries, and enabling several social modules.
  >
  > Despite a bunch of other social modules, this module fits exactly if you want simple share buttons without worrying about messy configurations.
  >
  > Easy Social is available both as blocks, attached to nodes, comments and also as a Views field.

## Modules with an unstable D7 release:

- [Follow](https://www.drupal.org/project/follow):

  > Follow adds sitewide and per user links that link to various social networking sites. The links reside in two blocks. The Follow Site block lists all the links for the site itself, and by default is visible on all pages. The Follow User block lists all the follow links for the user and is visible only on user profile pages.
- [AddThis](http://drupal.org/project/addthis):

  > Provides an AddThis.com button or toolbox to let your users share your content to social network sites.
- [Social media](https://www.drupal.org/project/socialmedia):

  > The Social media module helps integrate your website with social media sites such as Twitter, Facebook and Google+. It provides an centralized way of managing social media profile information and plug-in widgets such as follow and share buttons.

## Recommended resources

For additional details, refer to these articles:

- [Comparison of Social Network connectors/Sharing modules](https://groups.drupal.org/node/28680).
- [The "best" social media modules](http://www.drupal4u.org/tips-and-tricks/best-social-media-modules).
- [4 Social Sharing Modules for Drupal](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/4-social-sharing-modules-drupal).
- [Top 5 Drupal Social Networking Modules for Bloggers](https://hostingreview360.com/top-5-drupal-social-networking-module).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want it at the top of each single blog entry...

In **Administration >> Structure >> Contentypes**,

1. select the content type where you want to place the share buttons. (In your case it maight be News content type)
2. Go to manage display and select the display mode where you need the buttons.
3. You should be able to see AddToAny in the Disabled section.
4. Move AddToAny at the top of the enabled fields section and click on save.

If you want to be at top of the page then you will need to

1. Go to /admin/structure/block, Select the region where you want the buttons
2. Click on "Place block"
3. Locate AddToAny buttons
4. Click on Place block
5. In the pop up window under Visibility, you will need to configure how to relate buttons with Drupal nodes. If you wan it only under News, and guessing your path to news is /news, you could select "Pages" here and add the following two lines:
   /news
   /news/*
   having ticked "Show for the listed pages"

I recommend you to make some tests with visibility options to understand how it works.

1. Click on "Save block" in the pop-up
2. Click on Save Blocks

Hope this helps!